# Rails Like returns match in full word need exact match

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So right now when i search for "cook" my search returns cookies.

I need it to return "cook" and then if nothing exists then return "cookies"

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  def search
    @sentence = Sentence.where("LOWER(verse) LIKE LOWER(?)", "%" + params[:search_term] + "%")
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, but may be not the efficient one since it will do query twice:

```
@sentence = Sentence.where("LOWER(verse) LIKE LOWER(?)", params[:search_term])
@sentence_alternatives = Sentence.where("LOWER(verse) LIKE LOWER(?)", "%#{params[:search_term]}%") if @sentence.blank?
```

Another way could be using `or` with `where`:

```
@sentence = Sentence.where("LOWER(verse) LIKE LOWER(?)", params[:search_term]).or.where("LOWER(verse) LIKE LOWER(?)", "%#{params[:search_term]}%")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@sentence = Sentence.where("LOWER(verse) LIKE LOWER(%?%)", params[:search_term])
```